# Unable to send emails from linux

Tags: linux, email

I am unable to send email from command prompt.
Checked `/var/spool/mail/` file and see this error:

```
<myname@company.com> host aserv0021.net.com[141.xxx.1xx.233] said:
553 5.1.8 <id@doooo-0.localdomain>... Domain of sender address
id@doooo-0.localdomain does not exist (in reply to MAIL FROM
command)

--8F9311E0709.1429732346/doooo-0.localdomain
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; doooo-0.localdomain
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 8F9311E0709
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; id@doooo-0.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 01:22:24 +0530 (IST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; myname@company.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.8
Remote-MTA: dns; aserv0021.mycompany.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 553 5.1.8 <id@doooo-0.localdomain>... Domain of
sender address id@doooo-0.localdomain does not exist

Return-Path: <id@doooo-0.localdomain>
Received: by doooo-0.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 5xxxx6)
    id 8F93xxx0709; Thu, 23 Apr 2015 01:22:24 +0530 (IST)
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2015 01:22:24 +0530
To: myname@company.com
Subject: No commit since previous build
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20150422195224.8F9311E0709@doooo-0.localdomain>
From: id@doooo-0.localdomain (myid id)
```

some email body text
xt from the attached returned message.

Kindly let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your machine needs a proper DNS hostname and one that the receiving MTA will accept mail from.

To prevent a lot of spam most mail agents (MTA's) have pretty strict rule checking and won't accept mail if various rules aren't met, including looking up the domain of the sender and verifying that it's a real domain.

Use the "hostname" command and see if you get something like

mumble.mycompany.com

as a result. The "localdomain" domain is usually a substitute when no real domain was configured in the machine.

You can temporarily setup a hostname using

hostname mumble.mycompany.com

but you should get a real hostname from your IT department and it gets set in the system in different ways depending on which linux you are using.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like no domain was configured on this OEL linux system. when I type "hostname" i just get this: doooo-0 . My /etc/hosts contain entry:  10.xxx.x.xx doooo-0 doooo-0.in.mycompany.com 12x.0.0.x localhost localhost.localdomian localhost2 localhost2.localdomain2   how do i setup hostname and where?

Comment: The hostname setup varies with different Linux distributions. You need to check the network setup documentation for OEL Linux. It also depends if you are using static IPs or DHCP.